# Passing params to callable doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to transform n XMLs to n PDFs in n threads. For this I am using the ExecutorService and limit the thread pool size to e.g. 10:

```
File[] files = getDocuments(sourceFolder);

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

List<Future<Integer>> threads = new ArrayList<>();

for (File source : files) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Creating thread for " + source.getName());
    }
    Callable<Integer> callable = new XMLToPDFCallable(source, FileNameUtils.getPdfTarget(source, targetFolder));
    Future<Integer> future = executorService.submit(callable);
    threads.add(future);
}
```

After I run a first test I observed that only one XML is transformed successfully and I also saw that the XMLToPDFCallable() always used the same parameters:

> TransformerExecutorService.startExecution - Creating thread for **test_bold.xml**
>   TransformerExecutorService.startExecution - Creating thread for **test_list_attach.xml**
>   TransformerExecutorService.startExecution - Creating thread for **test_underlined.xml** 
>   XMLToPDFCallable.call XMLToPDFCallable(File **test_bold.xml**, File test_bold.pdf)
>   XMLToPDFCallable.call XMLToPDFCallable(File **test_underlined.xml**, File test_underlined.pdf)
>   XMLToPDFCallable.call XMLToPDFCallable(File **test_underlined.xml**, File test_underlined.pdf)
>   XMLToPdf.transform - **test_underlined.xml**
>
> XMLToPdf.transform - **test_underlined.xml**
>
> XMLToPdf.transform - **test_underlined.xml**
>
> XMLParser. - XMLParser(File **test_underlined.xml**)
>
> XMLParser. - XMLParser(File **test_underlined.xml**)
>
> XMLParser. - XMLParser(File **test_underlined.xml**)
>
> Result of FutureTask@4c90265b: 1
>   Result of FutureTask@bc647a2: 1
>   Result of FutureTask@688e2b8: 1

XMLToPDFCallable class:

```
public class KMToPDFCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
...
public XMLToPDFCallable(File source, File target) {

    this.source = source;
    this.target = target;
}

@Override
public Integer call() throws Exception {
    logger.debug("call() of Instance XMLToPDFCallable(File " + source.getName() + ", File " + target.getName() + ") ");
    xmlToPdf = new XMLToPdf();
    if(xmlToPdf.transform(source, target)) {
        status = STATUS_FINISHED;
    } else {
        status = STATUS_ABORTED;
    }
    kmToPdf = null;
    return status;
}
```

XMLToPDF class (simple class):

```
public boolean transform(File src, File target) {
        ...
        // the XML parser
        logger.debug(src.getName());
        xmlParser = new XMLParser(src);
        ...
```

XMLParser class (also simple class):

```
public XMLParser(File xml) {
        logger.debug("XMLParser(File " + xml.getName() + ")");
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(xml);
            builder.reset();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
```

So why does XMLToPDFCallable.call always uses the same file instead of the file I passed in the constructor?

Comment: Is the getDocuments(...) method returning the correct files for that directory?

Comment: yes it does, but I am more cussiose that logger in the call() methode prints only 2 files for 3 threads and the logger in the transform() method prints 1 file for all 3 threads?

Comment: My guess is that `source` is static. Show us the complete real code.

Comment: @JBNizet you are my hero! Damn I feel stupid now :P